# useNavigate remains on the same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I wish to navigate the login page to the main page after an admin clicks the login button. However, it remains to be on login page after I login with an admin account.

I use the useNavigate hook in the Login page and expect that the flow will be like: click login button -> handleClick function -> admin value in App.js change to true -> navigate to home page.

However, the page is not navigated even when loginSuccess is evoked on Redux developer tools and the admin value in App.js remains to be false unless I refresh the Login page. After I refresh the login page, it can be navigated to home page.

Can anyone please kindly help me out? I wish to navigate the home page once the admin click the login button, instead of clicking the login button and refreshing the login page to navigate to the home page. I tried to solve this for a few days already, but still couldn't figure this out.

App.js

```
function App() {
  //admin state is to deny non-admin access
  const [admin, setAdmin] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.getItem("persist:root") &&
      JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root")).login)
        .currentUser &&
      setAdmin(
        JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root")).login)
          .currentUser.isAdmin
      );
  });

  return (
    <Router>
      {admin && <Topbar />}
      <div className="container">
        {admin && <Sidebar />}
        <Routes>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            element={admin ? <Home /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
          />

          //shows login page as the first page
          <Route
            path="/login"
            element={!admin ? <Login /> : <Navigate to="/" />}
          />
          {admin && (
            <>
              <Route path="/users" element={<UserList />} />
              <Route path="/user/:userId" element={<User />} />
              <Route path="/newUser" element={<NewUser />} />
              <Route path="/products" element={<ProductList />} />
              <Route path="/product/:productId" element={<Product />} />
              <Route path="/newproduct" element={<NewProduct />} />
            </>
          )}
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
```

Login.jsx

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    login(dispatch, { username, password });
    navigate("/");
  };
```

apiCalls.js

```
export const login = async (dispatch, user) => {
  dispatch(loginStart());
  try {
    const res = await publicRequest.post("/auth/login", user);
    dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(loginFailure());
  }
};
```

Comment: Please add your whole code in a codesandbox and attach the link. Code like this is harder to debug and the whole code need to be looked at to solve the problem. We cannot find out the problem by looking at just some components and not the others.

Comment: @AravindKrishna Here's the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-germain-xzq5g5?file=/src/Login.jsx. Please kindly check.